# How to send post data (that contains 2 parameters) to https server via Socket Programming in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I saw a form in web, if i give code(R),vehicle number , it will give some information , now i want to get that information via socket programming.I have written code but it hangs

URL : https://aptransport.in/CFSTONLINE/Reports/VehicleRegistrationSearch.aspx

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class TestAP {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

int port = 443; // default https port


try{
URL url = new URL("https://aptransport.in/CFSTONLINE/Reports/VehicleRegistrationSearch.aspx");

String path=url.getFile();
//  int port = url.getPort();
String host = url.getHost();

        System.out.println("Step 0 : Connecting to Server");
        Socket cliSocket = new Socket(host,port);
        System.out.println("Step 1 : Connection Established ");


            System.out.println("Step 2 :  Creating Request");
        String data1 = URLEncoder.encode("ctl00$OnlineContent$ddlInput", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("R",        "UTF-8")        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("ctl00$OnlineContent$txtInput", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("AP31BF2942", "UTF-8");


            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliSocket.getOutputStream()));

             bw.write("POST " + path + " HTTPS/1.0\r\n");
             bw.write("Host: " + host + "\r\n");
             bw.write("Content-Length: " + data1.length() + "\r\n");
                 bw.write("Pragma: cache\r\n");
             bw.write("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate\r\n");
             bw.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");   
         bw.write("\r\n");
         bw.write(data1);

                 bw.flush();


    System.out.println("Step 3 :  Request Sent ");

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliSocket.getInputStream()));
        String line;
    System.out.println("Step 4 : Getting Input Stream");
    StringBuffer serverData = new StringBuffer("");

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      serverData.append(line);      
}

System.out.println(" \r\n \r\n ******* Data From Server Start : ******* \r\n  \r\n \r\n"+serverData+" \r\n \r\n ******* Data From                   Server End  ********* \r\n \r\n ");    

String data = serverData.toString();

 bw.close();
 rd.close();

}catch(java.net.UnknownHostException uh){
System.out.println("UH : Host Not Found ");    
}catch(IOException ioe){
System.out.println("IO Exp "+ioe.getMessage());    
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Exp "+e.getMessage());    
}


}
}
```

> IO Exp Connection reset java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)  at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)  at
>   TestAP.main(TestAP.java:59)

Comment: Does it throw an exception? If so; what message do you get? You say, "It hangs" If you were to inspect the request through Fiddler, what do you see?

Comment: until  System.out.println("Step 4 : Getting Input Stream"); it got executed , then i got IOException

Comment: Tell us more.  Take out the `catch(IOException ioe)` line and the `catch(Exception e)` line and just let that exception get thrown and then show us the stack trace from it.  You want our help, but you aren't providing nearly enough information for us to help you.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker i have edited

Comment: Before sending any HTTP message, you should handle the SSL handshake as you're connecting to the secure port and the server expects that negotiation.

Comment: Is there a good reason you want the socket API and not HttpsUrlConnection? With socket you pretty much need to implement the whole HTTPS protocol (handshake etc.), which i way more complicated than just plain HTTP.

Comment: All of the above plus: there is no `HTTPS/1.0` - it has to be `HTTP/1.0` as the SSL/TLS is one layer below the HTTP-layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea here would be to use `HttpsURLConnection`, which would handle most of the protocol details for you.  If you really want to use a socket, using an `SSLSocket` instead of vanilla `Socket` will at least handle the SSL/TLS part of the protocol.

Here are links to the Javadoc for these two classes.  You'll need to understand some associated classes as well, but this will get you started.

Javadoc for HttpURLConnection:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Javadoc for SSLSocket:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html